# Submitting form to PHP

Tags: plugins, php, functions, theme-development, forms

I am submitting a form to PHP edit post metadata. The logic I built is having multiple "ifisset" to execute different parts of the requirements based on the inputs.

There are 4 issets, the PHP should always execute 1 from set a, and 1 from set b"

set a
Individual vs Organisation

set b
Mailing adddress is same as billing vs is different

I have tried keeping 1 "ifisset" and it works fine, but 4 together seem to interfere with each other.

```
if(isset($_POST['Client_Type_Edit']) == 'Individual'){
            
    $Client_ID=$_POST['Client_ID'];
    $Client_Name_Edit=$_POST['Client_Name_Edit'];
    $Client_Type_Edit=$_POST['Client_Type_Edit'];
    $Client_Managers_Edit=$_POST['Client_Managers_Edit'];
    $Client_Summary_Edit=$_POST['Client_Summary_Edit'];
    $Client_Description_Edit=$_POST['Client_Description_Edit'];
    $Client_Assignee_Edit=$_POST['Client_Assignee_Edit'];
    $Email_1_Edit=$_POST['Email_1_Edit'];
    $Email_2_Edit=$_POST['Email_2_Edit'];
    $Telephone_1_Edit=$_POST['Telephone_1_Edit'];
    $Telephone_2_Edit=$_POST['Telephone_2_Edit'];
    $Mobile_1_Edit=$_POST['Mobile_1_Edit'];
    $Mobile_2_Edit=$_POST['Mobile_2_Edit'];
    $Fax_1_Edit=$_POST['Fax_1_Edit'];
    $Fax_2_Edit=$_POST['Fax_2_Edit'];
            
    $New_Meta_Individual = array
    
        (
        'Client_Name'    => $Client_Name_Edit,
        'Client_Type'    => $Client_Type_Edit,
        'Client_Managers'    => $Client_Managers_Edit,
        'Client_Summary' =>$Client_Summary_Edit,
        'Client_Description' =>$Client_Description_Edit,
        'Email_1'    => $Email_1_Edit,
        'Email_2'    => $Email_2_Edit,
        'Telephone_1'    => $Telephone_1_Edit,
        'Telephone_2'    => $Telephone_2_Edit,
        'Mobile_1'    => $Mobile_1_Edit,
        'Mobile_2'    => $Mobile_2_Edit,
        'Fax_1'    => $Fax_1_Edit,
        'Fax_2'    => $Fax_2_Edit,
        );
        
        delete_post_meta( $Client_ID,'Fax_2_A',null);
        delete_post_meta( $Client_ID, 'Email_1_A',null);
        delete_post_meta( $Client_ID, 'Client_Assignee',null);

        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $Client_ID,
            'post_name' => $Client_Name_Edit, 
            'post_content'=> $Client_Summary_Edit,
            'post_title'=> $Client_Name_Edit,
            'meta_input'=> $New_Meta_Individual,));
            
            $Client_Name_Current=$_POST['Client_Name_Current'];
            $Current_Client_Directory = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name_Current";

            $New_Client_Directory = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name_Edit";


            rename($Current_Client_Directory,$New_Client_Directory);
        }
        
if(isset($_POST['Client_Type_Edit']) == 'Organisation'){
            $New_Meta_Organisation = array
        (
        'Client_Name'    => $Client_Name_Edit,
        'Client_Type'    => $Client_Type_Edit,
        'Client_Managers'    => $Client_Managers_Edit,
        'Client_Summary' =>$Client_Summary_Edit,
        'Client_Description' =>$Client_Description_Edit,
        'Client_Assignee'    => $Client_Assignee_Edit,
        'Email_1'    => $Email_1_Edit,
        'Email_2'    => $Email_2_Edit,
        'Telephone_1'    => $Telephone_1_Edit,
        'Telephone_2'    => $Telephone_2_Edit,
        'Mobile_1'    => $Mobile_1_Edit,
        'Mobile_2'    => $Mobile_2_Edit,
        'Fax_1'    => $Fax_1_Edit,
        'Fax_2'    => $Fax_2_Edit,
        
        'Email_1_A'    => $Email_1_A_Edit,
        'Email_2_A'    => $Email_2_A_Edit,
        'Telephone_1_A'    => $Telephone_1_A_Edit,
        'Telephone_2_A'    => $Telephone_2_A_Edit,
        'Mobile_1_A'    => $Mobile_1_A_Edit,
        'Mobile_2_A'    => $Mobile_2_A_Edit,
        'Fax_1_A'    => $Fax_1_A_Edit,
        'Fax_2_A'    => $Fax_2_A_Edit,
        );
        
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $Client_ID,
            'post_name' => $Client_Name_Edit, 
            'post_content'=> $Client_Summary_Edit,
            'post_title'=> $Client_Name_Edit,
            'meta_input'=> $New_Meta_Organisation,
    ));
    
        $Client_Name_Current=$_POST['Client_Name_Current'];
        $Current_Client_Directory = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name_Current";
        $New_Client_Directory = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Directory/Clients/$Client_Name_Edit";


         rename($Current_Client_Directory,$New_Client_Directory);
            
        }
        
if(isset($_POST['Same_as_billing_Edit']) == 'Same as billing address'){
            $New_Meta_Same_Address = array
        (
        
        'Address_Line_1_1'    => $Address_Line_1_1_Edit,
        'Address_Line_2_1'    => $Address_Line_2_1_Edit,
        'City_1'    => $City_1_Edit,
        'Country_1'    => $Country_1_Edit,
        'Postal_Code_1'    => $Postal_Code_1_Edit,
        'Address_Line_1_2'    => $Address_Line_1_1_Edit,
        'Address_Line_2_2'    => $Address_Line_2_1_Edit,
        'City_2'    => $City_1_Edit,
        'Country_2'    => $Country_1_Edit,
        'Postal_Code_2'    => $Postal_Code_1_Edit,
        );
        
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $Client_ID,
            'post_name' => $Client_Name_Edit, 
            'post_content'=> $Client_Summary_Edit,
            'post_title'=> $Client_Name_Edit,
            'meta_input'=> $New_Meta_Same_Address,
    ));
    
    
            
        }

if(isset($_POST['Same_as_billing_Edit']) == NULL){
            $New_Meta_Different_Address = array
        (
        
        'Address_Line_1_1'    => $Address_Line_1_1_Edit,
        'Address_Line_2_1'    => $Address_Line_2_1_Edit,
        'City_1'    => $City_1_Edit,
        'Country_1'    => $Country_1_Edit,
        'Postal_Code_1'    => $Postal_Code_1_Edit,
        'Address_Line_1_2'    => $Address_Line_1_2_Edit,
        'Address_Line_2_2'    => $Address_Line_2_2_Edit,
        'City_2'    => $City_2_Edit,
        'Country_2'    => $Country_2_Edit,
        'Postal_Code_2'    => $Postal_Code_2_Edit,
        );
        
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $Client_ID,
            'post_name' => $Client_Name_Edit, 
            'post_content'=> $Client_Summary_Edit,
            'post_title'=> $Client_Name_Edit,
            'meta_input'=> $New_Meta_Different_Address,
    ));
    
    
        }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you're gonna add some sanitization to this.

Comment: What is sanitization? I am extremely new to PHP and have no educational background in programming either

Comment: [https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to combine `isset` with a value comparison, and that's not how it works. You should rewrite this:

`if(isset($_POST['Client_Type_Edit']) == 'Individual')`

to this:

`if ( isset( $_POST['Client_Type_Edit'] ) && 'Individual' === $_POST['Client_Type_Edit'] )`

This is checking to make sure that `$_POST['Client_Type_Edit']` is set AND the value is equal to "Individual".

Now repeat that for all of them.